# Using lower percentile data points in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to create a yearly indexed dataframe, with the data only being from a certain percentile (the lower 10% of data from each year, etc.).

Here is part of the data frame so far. I am aware of the quartile function, but am unaware of how to have it be indexed to take the quartile of each block of yearly data.

```
Year    HFC Altitude
1036    2009    49.0    10035.0
1201    2009    47.3    13540.0
1200    2009    47.6    13540.0
1199    2009    47.7    11322.0
1023    2009    45.7    11375.0
... ... ... ...
175 2019    107.6   17724.0
180 2019    109.5   11721.0
195 2019    109.1   13757.0
88  2019    108.1   10900.0
12  2019    109.6   15813.0
```

So I really just need to find a method in which I can take all the individual years and only have the quartile I request be represented for each year. Anything helps, thanks in advance

Comment: check out `pandas.qcut`

Comment: So for a year with 20 rows, you're looking to have X (e.g. 80) per-cent of the rows filtered out, and only 20% left in?

Comment: I want to filter out values that are above a certain amount. For each year, I'd like a method to have the data be limited to the lower 20% values, the upper 80%, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do that (in a couple of steps, for clarity, and keeping the bottom 33% of the data per year):

```
df["keep"] = df.groupby("Year")["Altitude"].apply(lambda x: x < x.quantile(.33))
df = df[df.keep]
```

The output, in this case, is:

```
    inx  Year    HFC  Altitude  keep
0  1036  2009   49.0   10035.0  True
3  1199  2009   47.7   11322.0  True
6   180  2019  109.5   11721.0  True
8    88  2019  108.1   10900.0  True
```

Comment: Simplified the answer a bit. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Really great! I appreciate this!